# Azure data factory slicestart format error

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-factory

I've been trying to set in SELECT parameter - slicestart time to gather just lately changed records:

```
WHERE pv.CreatedAt >= \\'{0:yyyyMMdd-HH}\\'', Time.AddHours(SliceStart, 0))"
```

and I got error:

> Database operation failed. Error message from database execution :
>   ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
>   database operation failed with the following error: 'Conversion failed
>   when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.',Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
>   database operation failed with the following error: 'Conversion failed
>   when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=241,'.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the Time.AddHours() function but passing 0 as a parameter which would add zero hours to the SliceStart value. If you did not intend to increment the SliceStart time try the following:

"sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('select ... where pv.CreatedAt >= \'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}\', SliceStart)"

Cheers,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Luis answer.

You have to make sure that the source date format must match the format of date being passed.

For eg:- If the source is Oracle then write query as below:-

```
WHERE TO_DATE(pv.CreatedAt,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= \\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}\\'',SliceStart))"
```